# Adding a color picker to a Scriptable Object

Tags: unity, scriptable-object

I made a Scriptable Object, and added a bunch of fields to it: string, Vector3, Sprite, etc.

So far, so good!   I'd like to also add a field with a simple color picker in it, that allows me to set the color of some text.

I see that I can easily add a Material and use the color from there, but I'm hoping there's a more direct way I can add a color picker to the Scriptable Object.  Anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Color scriptable object field]

This was achieved pretty easily by adding the following in your class that inherits `ScriptableObject`

```
public Color RarityColor;
```

The `Color` type as `public` should get it to show

Comment: Wow thanks!  I had tried "color" but it didn't work... didn't realize that it was case sensitive!  Funny thing is that "string" wasn't case sensitive...

Comment: Read the API documentation. [It explains that lowercase `string` is an alias of `System.String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/), and [the Unity docs show the correct capitalization of `Color` and `Color32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html).

Comment: Many thanks, I'm just getting started on my programming journey so appreciate the link to the API docs!

Comment: Note: There are a lot of ways to input color. Gradients are a common solution for Brick Breaker games like mine, and they're serializable. 

Check some of the built in scriptable objects for more possibilities, eg, TextMesh Pro's Color Gradient (Right click in your Assets folder and look under Create).